# Looping through all columns in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find a way of evaluating all fields in many tables and return % of the data filled in. i need to look for specific things rather than just NULL. 
So for instance in the client table, it would return all fields and say Client Name 45% completed, 
Address 90% Completed etc.

I need to search on NULL, Blank, UNCODED, -1 vs row count

some of the tables have more than 30+ fields hence why I think a loop my be best.

```
select 
cast(100 - ((select cast(count([ClientName])as decimal(10,2))
from [dbo].[Client]
where 
   [ClientName] is null 
or [ClientName] = '' 
 or [ClientName] = 'UNCODED'
or [ClientName] = -1
 )
 /
   (select cast(count([ClientName])as decimal(10,2))  
from [dbo].[Client]
where 
   [ClientName] is not null 
or [ClientName] <> '' 
 or [ClientName] <> 'UNCODED'
or [ClientName] <> -1
 ))as decimal(10,2)) as '%Completed'
```

The below gets me the table names

```
select 
     c.column_id,c.name
    from sys.columns            c
        inner join sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
        where o.name = 'Client'
    order by c.column_id
```

I'm new to SQL and trying to get my head round variables and loops but just not getting it.

Comment: I think your information is incomplete. You say nothing about the results you get and you do not ask a concrete question. If you don't get the results you expect, note that a percentage is calculated by dividing a part with the *total*. You divide a part with the remainder. And you do not determine the remainder correctly. If the "part" is determined with WHERE-clause A OR B OR C OR D, you could determine the remainder by either using NOT (A OR B OR C OR D) or using NOT A AND NOT B AND NOT C AND NOT D.

Comment: Ah. I re-read your question and I understand it better now.

Comment: Another detail to regard is the behavior of COUNT(*) vs. COUNT([fieldname]). The former includes all row values and the latter includes only the non-NULL values of the specified field!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the dynamic SQL query you need using simple string concatenation from `sys.columns`, just don't try to add an `ORDER BY` as that behavior is undefined and in many cases will leave out rows inexplicably.

```
-- given these variables/parameters:
DECLARE @c int, @t nvarchar(511) = N'dbo.Client';

-- only proceed if this is actually an object (some protection from SQL injection):
IF OBJECT_ID(@t) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  -- we can get the row count from metadata instead of scanning the table an extra time:
  SELECT @c = SUM(rows) FROM sys.partitions 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@t) AND index_id IN (0,1);

  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT [table] = N''' + @t + N'''',
          @col nvarchar(max) = N',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'[% $c$ complete] = '
               + N'CONVERT(decimal(5,2), 100.0*SUM(CASE WHEN $qc$ IS NULL '
               + N'OR $qc$ = SPACE(0) OR RTRIM($qc$) IN (''UNCODED'',''-1'') '
               + N'THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)/@c)';

  SELECT @sql += REPLACE(REPLACE(@col, N'$c$', name), N'$qc$', QUOTENAME(name))
    FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@t);

  SELECT @sql += N' FROM @t;';
  SELECT @sql = REPLACE(@sql, N'@t', @t);

  PRINT @sql;
  --EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql, @params = N'@c int', @c = @c;
END
```

When you are satisfied the output looks like you expect, uncomment the `EXECUTE`. Note that you may have to filter out certain data types (I don't know what happens with XML, binary, or types like hierarchyid or geography, and don't have the energy to test those right now).

Comment: Hi Aaron ,   Wow! I'm very grateful for your answer, not very familiar with dynamic SQL however, the code works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a performance benefit to `LEN(RTRIM($qc$))`? From [`Len`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing spaces." From [`RTrim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "Returns a character string after truncating all trailing spaces." The both deal only with "spaces" and not other whitespace characters.

Comment: @HABO `RTRIM()` is only there to facilitate a conversion from numeric / datetime types so they can be treated like strings. I could use an explicit `CONVERT`, but to what? The only safe one would be converting every single column to  `nvarchar(max)`. As for spaces, well, the OP didn't specify how they wanted to handle an entry like `tab` or `lf`. `LEN(x) = 0` is just a way to say `x = ''` without adding additional double/quadruple single quotes into a dynamic SQL expression.